Show directories added in a commit
Is there a way to show directories and directories only -- not files -- that were added between commit A and commit B?
git show and git diff docs don't seem to have anything obvious, and I can't find an answer online.

Note that git diff A B --name-only --diff-filter=A will show you all files that were added from A to B. This may seem like you're close, but in order to know which folders are new because of adding those files, you'd still need to compare that against the folder structure of A, and at that point you might as well skip the Git diff and instead use something like Wes Hardaker's answer.

git does not actually store "directories" in a commit -- it stores files.  And diff out put (whether from git or other tools) generally don't show you directories either.
You can probably hack something together by looking at the output of comparing two calls from git ls-tree --name-only -r COMMIT.
Very quick hack (there are certainly better ways):
$ git ls-tree --name-only -r OLDER_COMMIT | sed 's#/[^/]*##' | sort | uniq > /tmp/one
$ git ls-tree --name-only -r NEWER_COMMIT | sed 's#/[^/]*##' | sort | uniq > /tmp/two
$ diff -u /tmp/one /tmp/two


It's simpler with -d. d for directory tree.  git ls-tree -d -r --name-only COMMIT. No sed required.

Yup. join -v2 <(git ls-tree --name-only -rd A)  <(git ls-tree --name-only -rd B).

Not related to the core of the answer provided, but I think it makes sense to clarity. Git does save directories... They are tree objects (a commit pointing to a tree object, for example). What it does not save are empty directories.
